# How to modify Http headers before executing request in spring boot mvc

Tags: spring, rest, spring-mvc, spring-boot

I have  multiple rest endpoints. userId (http header) is common in all endpoints. I want to apply a logic, let say set its default value if not provided or trim it if is provided in request before request enters the method (for eg: heartbeat). How can we achieve this in spring boot rest mvc.

```
@RestController
public class MyResource {



        @RequestMapping(value = "/heartbeat", method= RequestMethod.GET)
        public String heartbeat (@RequestHeader (value="userId", required=false) String userId) 
        {
           ...
        }
    }
```

Comment: You may use an interceptor

Answer (score 4):

Can you try this?

```
@Configuration
@Slf4j
public class HttpHeaderModificationConfig implements Filter {

  private static final String HEADER_DEMO_NAME = "name";

  @Override
  public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain)
      throws IOException, ServletException {
    final HttpServletRequest req = (HttpServletRequest) request;
    // modify HTTP Request Header
    final HttpServletRequestWrapper reqWrapper = new HttpServletRequestWrapper(req) {

      @Override
      public String getHeader(String name) {
        if (HEADER_DEMO_NAME.equals(name)) {
          return "Changed";
        }
        return super.getHeader(name);
      }
    };
    log.info("After Changed with Name {}", reqWrapper.getHeader(HEADER_DEMO_NAME));
    chain.doFilter(reqWrapper, response);
  }

}
```

Comment: I would add @Order(Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE) if the modification should be before any logic

Comment: works very well

Answer (score 0):

One option i can think of using Filters i.e. create a Filter to check for the header `userId` and trim it if its present or provide it a default value if its not present and store it in another header lets say `customUserId`. In your controller you can comfortably use your custom headers to be sure of that it will be valid as per your requirements. You can refer to the below article for creating a generic bean

https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-add-filter